# How to handle select event in select box?

Tags: reactjs

Hi I am trying to implement select box in my react application. I am using npm from https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-select. Below is my code.

```
const options = [
  { value: 'Current', label: 'Current' },
  { value: 'Future', label: 'Future' },
  { value: 'Closed', label: 'Closed' },
];
export class EditParametersPanelComponent extends React.Component {
 this.state = {
 selectedOption: null,
 }
handleChange(selectedOption) {
    this.setState({ selectedOption });
    console.log('Option selected:', selectedOption);
  }

render() {
    const { selectedOption } = this.state;
       return (
       <Select
              instanceId="storeFilter"
              value={selectedOption}
              onChange={this.handleChange}
              options={options}
              placeholder="Store"
            />,
         );
  }
}
```

I am able to render select box in web page. Whenever I click on any one of the option I am getting below errors.

```
1. Uncaught TypeError: this.setState is not a function
2. Warning: Failed prop type: You provided a `checked` prop to a form field without an `onChange` handler. This will render a read-only field. If the field should be mutable use `defaultChecked`. Otherwise, set either `onChange` or `readOnly`.
```

Can someone help me to identify and fix this error? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You need to bind `this.handleChange` to `this`. https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to use arrow function for binding

```
handleChange = selectedOption => {
    this.setState({ selectedOption });
    console.log('Option selected:', selectedOption);
  }
```

or you can use other way below

```
<Select
              instanceId="storeFilter"
              value={selectedOption}
              onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}
              options={options}
              placeholder="Store"
            />,
```

Comment: Hi Thanks KKangil. I changed as above. Now started getting below error. Parsing error: Unexpected token =. Do I need to change anything here?

Comment: Can you get the result `console.log('Option selected:', selectedOption);`?

Comment: yes now. Thanks a lot for helping. I added   this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);